# Why can't I query MongoDB id field with strings?

Tags: mongodb

If I wish to access a document by id, and I happen to know the id is say: 557afc91c0b20703009f7ede, why do I need to use the ObjectId function to query the database, like so:

```
db.mydocs.find(ObjectId("557afc91c0b20703009f7ede"))
```

rather than the apparently more obvious:

```
db.mydocs.find("557afc91c0b20703009f7ede")
```

or:

```
db.mydocs.find({_id: "557afc91c0b20703009f7ede"})
```

?

Comment: Google works: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/ and explains exactly what an ObjectId is. It is Bytes. Not a string. If you are asking why doesn't it just convert? Then the answer for a "schemaless database" is MongoDB does not really know ( in itself ) which "type" of data is stored in `_id`. It doesn't have to be an ObjectId

Comment: Thanks @BlakesSeven - I find it "surprising" behaviour. I'm not sure why I'm being aggressively downvoted, it's a reasonable question.

Comment: Nothing surprizing. It's bytes as said. The Hex string is just a representation. As I said an `_id` does not have to be an `ObjectId` and it does not "always" have to contain the same type. MongoDB is "schemaless" so the database itself knows nothing about which type to expect nor enforces that rule. External libraries such as "mongoose" (example) allow you to define a "schema". Then your model objects can reasonably assume that your string needs to be cast to an ObjectId without your intervention. But only then. It's a code libary thing and not a "database" thing with MongoDB.

Comment: I see, it's because the ID can have different formats. If I run a $group query for example the ID of the generated document set is generated from the group criteria.

Answer (score 4):

From [mongodb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/):

> ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type

ObjectId is therefore not a string. What you are actually doing is building this 12-byte object from its string representation.

Answer (score 0):

Because when one row is inserted in db then one id is generated in ObjectId format not in string with column name _id.

Comment: Hi @sorma - that's true, but not explanatory.